# Conditionally run command in bash shell script using if/fi construct

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I am trying to run the following command if a variable, A, is greater than zero. A is set prior to all of this.

> pybot --rerunfailed $HUDSON_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/$PAST_BUILD/robot-plugin/output.xml

and run the following commands if this variable, A, is not greater than zero

> pybot --suite "$TEST_SUITE" --test "$TEST_CASE" --exclude $TAGS_TO_EXCLUDE

How can I do this with an if/then/else/fi construct?

Comment: `if [[ $A -gt 0 ]]; then somestuff;else some other stuff; fi`. basic googling would have yielded this result in less than 10s

Comment: Thanks, but you must not have read my question. I am trying to execute one command under the if and another under an else. I did do some googling, but I was unable to find an answer to this specific question.

Comment: This does just that. Execute `somestuff` if A>0, and `some other stuff` otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `if/else/fi` snippet in `BASH` using arithmetic evaluator `((...))`:

```
if (( A > 0)); then
   pybot --rerunfailed "$HUDSON_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/$PAST_BUILD/robot-plugin/output.xml"
else
   pybot --suite "$TEST_SUITE" --test "$TEST_CASE" --exclude "$TAGS_TO_EXCLUDE"
fi
```

**PS:** Better to quote all your BASH variable in quotes to avoid problems due to unexpected shell expansion or presence of spaces/new line in variables.

Comment: It may be nice to also suggest quoting the arguments.

Comment: Thanks @konsolebox. I added this in my answer.